# How to create network graph from csv in different format in R?

Tags: r, networking, graph

So I have a table formatted like this: 
http://www.sharecsv.com/s/a12e5ce610261b9f0d315b56d7a88b19/testdata.csv
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jwfzm.jpg

My goal is to have each Auth (Auth1 to 10) representing a node, and if they are in the same row/group it means they are connected and therefore have a link, so maybe have a matrix of every Auth by every Auth, with the name of times they appear together adds 1 to their matrix, if that makes sense.

I've managed to pull out the list of authors but I have no idea how to calculate how many times they appear together to form this matrix, can anyone help?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please do not post pictures of data since we can't test with them.

Comment: How would I share it?

Comment: This link I provided shows how to create useful reproducible examples.

Comment: Here is the data: http://www.sharecsv.com/s/a12e5ce610261b9f0d315b56d7a88b19/testdata.csv